# Qt + Android - Necessitas - top level windows decoration

Tags: android, qt, window-decoration

Recently I've built my first Qt application for Android (using necessitas).

It works fine but (full-screen application) ...

The message boxes are not decorated and located always in the top-left corner of the screen.

How can I simple decorate them with standard decoration and restore centering behavior?

Comment: Re-implement or create your own class.

Comment: not an option. I want to use standard QMessageDlg.

Comment: Well, then you are stuck with standard drawing method for the time being. I had the same problem and had to reimplement the paint event so that it puts 80% black over the old screen and displays the dialog in the middle.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234424/issue-with-qmessagebox-cant-change-its-position) helped with position.